# Form submit via AngularJs with Spring - Annoation not mapped to request

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, form-submit

I have to do a form submit through angularjs and java layer has to process the request.

**Sample Request:**

> Request Header:

```
PUT /student/form HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 154
Origin: mydomain
Accept-Language: en
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

> Form Data:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryJ8UG5IFHivltab5e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="formData"

[object Object]
------WebKitFormBoundaryJ8UG5IFHivltab5e--
```

In Java,

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
@Path("/student")
public class FormSubmitService {

    @PUT
    @Path("/form")
    @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    public void saveForm(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
                         @RequestBody FormDomainRequest formDomainRequest) {
        LOG.debug("requets from browser");
    }
}
```

But i could not get the form data in request to map to my pojo class "FormDomainRequest"

Please let me know there is there any wrong in my service layer!